# How to remove Image files with MAGMI

Tags: magmi

I am using MAGMI and it's plugin Product Deleter to clean up my Magento catalog.
The products are correctly removed, but I just noticed that their image files are still there.

Does anyone know if it is possible to delete the product images with MAGMI?
Is there any other batch tool to do that?

Comment: Magmi relies a lot on direct db interaction. So when you are using it, you risk this kind of inconsistencies. You will probably need to clean it manually if there is no plugin for this.

Answer (score 2):

This module allows you to clean up all the unused product images:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/image-clean.html

The modules isn't the cleanest code wise but does the job. Is this something that solves your problem?

Comment: The above module is an essential for any Magento store with a large catalogue. We use it at least once a week to clear images for deleted products etc. Great tool!